# passing function name as string in jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I don't know if the title of this question is right or not, so please if someone has a better description edit it.

I've anchor element with custom attribute as follows (Update: according to @Rune solution and @Shauna comment)

```
<a href="#" class="call-method" data-url="/Pages/mustafa/test_dialoge.aspx/GetDate" data-data="" data-success="handleResult">call me</a>
```

Where data-url, data-data, data-success, and data-error are custom attributes

Then i use the following snippet to attach some scripts to it

```
$('.call-method').live('click', function () {

    var obj = $(this);
    var options = new Object();

    options.url = obj.attr('data-url').toString();
    options.success = obj.attr('data-success');
    options.error = obj.attr('data-error');
    options.complete = obj.attr('data-complete');

    var _options = JSON.stringify(options);

    callServerGetMethod(_options);

});


  var callServerGetMethod = function (options) {
    var _options = new Object();
    var self = this;
    if (typeof options === 'string') {
      _options = JSON.parse(options, function (key, value) {
        if (typeof self[value] === 'function') {
          return eval(self[value]);
        }
        return value;
      });
    }

    $.ajax(
      {
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        error:
          function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log(xhr.statusText);
            console.log(thrownError);
          }
      }, $.extend(_options));
  };
```

Now I got the following error in browser console

```
SyntaxError {popStackFrame: function}
arguments: Array[1]
get message: function () { [native code] }
get stack: function () { [native code] }
set message: function () { [native code] }
set stack: function () { [native code] }
type: "unexpected_token"
__proto__: Error
arguments: undefined
constructor: function SyntaxError() { [native code] }
name: "SyntaxError"
stack: undefined
type: undefined
__proto__: d
```

Comment: Just a side note - "data" is the prefix for [custom data in HTML](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/). While not using it probably won't hurt things (except readability, as there are "onError" and "onSuccess" HTML hooks, which may be confused with your custom "on-error" and "on-success" attributes), it might be a good idea to keep your code standards-compliant and rename your custom attributes to include the "data-" prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a string and not a function to the ajax options which is why it doesn't work.

in your example you might as well have written

```
callServerGetMethod(url, data, function(msg) {
      alert("error " + msg);
    },
      function() {
        alert('comepleted');
      }
    , "handleSuccess");
```

notice that the last argument is a plain string

instead you will have to pass a function the most common way to do this is to attach the functions using JavaScript rather than custom attributes.

Depending on how you treat the data attribute you might be able to use that attribute.

```
<a href="#" 
   class="call-method" 
   options="{url: "/Pages/mustafa/test_dialoge.aspx/GetDate",data:{param1: 1, param2: 2}, success:handleResult,error:doOnError}"
>call me</a>

var callServerGetMethod = function (options) {
    var self = this;
    if(typeof options === 'string'){
      options = JSON.parse(options,function (key, value) {
         if (typeof self[value] === 'function') {
            return self[value];
         }
         return value;
      });
    }
    $.ajax($.extend({type: "POST"},options);
};
```

if you can't use the data attribute like this then simply construct the options argument based on the attribute values

```
var call = function (url, data, onError, onComplete, onSuccess) {
    return callServerGetMethod('{"url":"' + url +'","data":' + data + ',"error":"' + onError + '","success":"' + onSuccess'"}');
}
```

alternatively you can define a function to turn a string into an already defined function

```
var string2function = function string2function(functionName){
     if (typeof functionName === 'function') return functionName;

     if(typeof functionName === 'string'){
         if (typeof self[functionName] === 'function') {
            return self[functionName];
         }
     }
     return null;
}
```

and then use it like this

options.success = string2function(obj.attr('data-success'));

Theoretically you could use `eval` on the attribute value however it's generally encouraged to avoid `eval`because of a lot of potential riscs associated with that funciton

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i need to specify the handler for function with the same syntax like the event handler, like this <a onclick="somefunction" />

Comment: $('.call-method').live('click', function () {
    var obj = $(this);
    var url = obj.attr('url');
    var data = obj.attr('data');
    var onSuccess = obj.attr('on-success');
    var onError = obj.attr('on-error');
    var onComplete = obj.attr('on-complete');

    //callServerGetMethod(url, data, onError, onComplete, onSuccess);
    var options = '{data: ' + data + ', success: ' + onSuccess + ', error: ' + onError + ', complete: ' + onComplete + '}';
    alert(options);
    callServerGetMethod(url, options);

  });

Comment: var callServerGetMethod = function (url, options) {
    $.ajax($.extend(
      {
        url: url,
        type: "POST"
      }, options));
  };

Comment: @MustafaMagdy in your example you are not really combining our methods. The key point in my method is that I'm passing a function to success you are in both versions passing a string which will not work

Comment: @MustafaMagdy the real question of course is why do you need to specify it like event handlers?

Comment: Because I need to separate the jquery from the html, i need to make it like a hocked framework

Comment: but #Rune, the `options` attribute in anchor was string, and u passed it to method as string, which I did in the last snippet... ?

Comment: @MustafaMagdy that's why I wrote `depending on how you treat the data attribute` I've updated the answer to show away of handling the data attribute that will work if the calling context (whatever 'this' refers to in callServerGetMethod) defines a method with the name

Comment: But there is no way to pass the function name like event handler in markup ??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24440/discussion-between-mustafa-magdy-and-rune-fs)